# Exclude a file form project at compile time swift3.2 - xcode

Tags: xcode, xctest, build-settings

I have one file which reference I have added in xcode main project target and test case both.

This file reference needs to be added to main project only when test cases are running.

I don't want to include it when I create main project build since this file is for testing purpose only.

What is the best way to remove reference from main project when test cases are not running?

Comment: Instead of repeating your question with different words, please choose which one you want to keep and close the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by using **`Exclude files`** setting from **xcode's build setting.**

I have added mock file reference to both app and test target.

Then for release and AppStore build configuration I have excluded mock file so that it doesn't any extra size in app store build.

Since test cases run only in debug mode. This is safe solution.